# Dasha SDK Jobs, queue

Tags: artificial-intelligence, dasha

When I use Dasha's old SDK, from another file with "dashaApp.enqueueJobs()" sended call number to the main Dasha.js file and I get the number, but in the new Dasha SDK how I can get the info sented from enqueueJobs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.dasha.ai/en-us/default/sdk/node-js/classes/conversationqueue

when you want to add entry

```
application.queue.push("key", {

  after: new Date(),

  before: new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000)

});
```

in main handler

```
application.queue.on("ready", async (key, conversation) => {

//key -- something for identification of job on your side, for example phone number
  conversation.input = getInput(key);

  const result = await conversation.execute();

});
```

Or you can use queue-less execution https://docs.dasha.ai/en-us/default/sdk/node-js/classes/application#createconversation

```
const dasha = require("@dasha.ai/sdk");

const app = await dasha.deploy("path/to/app");

....

const conv = app.createConversation({

  foo: 123,

});
const result = await conv.execute();
```